# javascript copying array to another

Tags: javascript

i have the following code snippet, where inside for loop the value to contain is not getting assigned, is this is the proper way to copy array to other.??

as here

```
  var groupCondition = "ALL-OF-THEM&ALL-OF-THEM&ALL-OF-THEM&ALL-OF-THEM&";
  var groupParam =    "rsTxTraceMsgAside&rsExpTraceMsgAside&rsTxTraceMsgBside&rsExpTraceMsgBside&#hp1TxTraceMsg&hp1ExpTraceMsg&#";



  var grpNameArr = groupParam.split("#");
  var groupcn= groupCondition.split("&");
  var m=grpNameArr.length;

var contain=new Array();
var cmds=new Array();
var ii;

for(ii=0;ii<(m-1);ii++)
{
   contain[ii] = groupCn[ii];
   cmds[ii] = grpNameArr[ii];
 }
```

Comment: `var groupcn=All,All,All,All;` is not how you create an array. Try `var groupcn=[All,All,All,All]; ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone an array you can use slice() method as mentioned in this page:

http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_414-copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object

```
var oldArray = ["mip", "map", "mop"];
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

your array declaration is wrong , it should be like :-

```
var groupcn=["All","All","All","All"]; 
var grpNameArr=["abc","def","ghi"];
```

Comment: Thats just for an example i took! it is an array and contains these values(its proper with array) but still issue comes while assigning value inside for loop

Answer (score 0):

So, after your edit, I see your problem was that you has some typo's in your variable names.

Replace:

```
var grpNameArr = groupParm.split("#");
var groupcn= groupCondtn.split("&");
```

With:

```
var grpNameArr = groupParam.split("#");
//                      ^ Missing `a` and `r`.
var groupCn= groupCondition.split("&");
//       ^ Capital C  ^ Missing `i`'s and `o`.
```

---

**Old Answer**

These 2 lines:

```
var groupcn = All,All,All,All; 
var grpNameArr = abc,def,ghi;
```

Are probably your problem.

What you're doing there is assigning the variable `All` to a new variable `groupcn`, then declaring `All` as a new variable, 3 times.

```
var groupcn=All,
    All, // new variable with the name `All`
    All, // new variable with the name `All`
    All; // new variable with the name `All`. These 3 override `All`
```

You'll need to initialize them like this:

```
var groupcn = [All,All,All,All]; 
var grpNameArr = [abc,def,ghi];
```

Other than that, assuming `m` is the length of `groupcn`, the code should work.

However, a shorter solution is to copy the arrays like this:

```
var contain = groupcn.slice();
var cmds = grpNameArr.slice();
```

Comment: @user1752557: Edited. With my change, the code works like it should, `contain` and `cmds` are both arrays with 2 entries (Since you split `groupParam` on `#`, it only had 2 entries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
var contain=groupcn.concat();
var cmds=grpNameArray.concat();
```

Answer (score -1):

Following mistakes were in the code

1. Using one loop for both the arrays. Since there length is not same two different loops should be used.
2. There was typo mistake in groupcn variable.

Check this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function chk()
{
  var groupCondition = "ALL-OF-THEM&ALL-OF-THEM&ALL-OF-THEM&ALL-OF-THEM&";
  var groupParam =    "rsTxTraceMsgAside&rsExpTraceMsgAside&rsTxTraceMsgBside&rsExpTraceMsgBside&#hp1TxTraceMsg&hp1ExpTraceMsg&#";



var grpNameArr = groupParam.split("#");
var groupcn= groupCondition.split("&");

var contain=new Array();
var cmds=new Array();
var ii;

for(ii=0;ii<(groupcn.length-1);ii++)
contain[ii] = groupcn[ii];

for(ii=0;ii<(grpNameArr.length-1);ii++)
cmds[ii] = grpNameArr[ii];

alert("groupcn   =  "+contain);
alert("grpNameArr   =  "+cmds);
}
</script>
<body onload="chk()">

</body>
```

Comment: Nope. Now `grpNameArr` is just a reference to `groupcn`. Anything changed in one of the arrays will also be changed in the other.